# ¿Por qué no devuelve ni un error ni los valores en return?

Tags: python, funciones

Tengo una pregunta, estoy haciendo un ejercicio donde tu insertas un numero en la función y te devuelve `True` si es divisible entre 13 y `False` si no lo es, pero hay tras hacer esta formula que en principio esta bien:

```
def divide_entre_13(x):

    restos = ([0, 13, 26, 39, 52, 65, 78, 91])

    while x > 91:
        x = abs(m.floor(x/10)-x%10*9)

        if x in restos:
            return True
```

no me devuelve ningún valor ni ningún error. En teoría debería devolverme el valor lógico de `True` o `False` pero nada.
las operaciones son correctas, tengo que hacerlo de esta forma pero debe haber algún error de sintaxis en algún lado o algo, no comprendo.

Comment: De hecho si te debe dar error de sintaxis indicando que estás usando return fuera de una función, en su lugar tal vez un print sea la mejor opción

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función retorna actualmente `True` o `None`, nunca retorna `False`.

**Toda función/método retorna en Python `None` por defecto**, es decir, si no se ejecuta ningún `return` explícito, la funciona retorna `None`.

Tienes dos situaciones en las que tu función termina retornando `None`:

- Si el número ingresado es menor o igual a 91.
- Si el número no es divisible entre 13 (no se cae en el `if` una vez agotado el `while`).

Estas dos situaciones debes corregirlas, por ejemplo:

```
import math

def divide_entre_13(x: int) -> bool:

    restos = {0, 13, 26, 39, 52, 65, 78, 91}

    if abs(x) in restos:
        return True

    while x > 91:
        x = abs(math.floor(x / 10) - x % 10 * 9)
        if x in restos:
            return True

    return False
```

> ```
> >>> for x in range(-100, 200):
>         if divide_entre_13(x):
>             print(x)
>
> -91
> -78
> -65
> -52
> -39
> -26
> -13
> 0
> 13
> 26
> 39
> 52
> 65
> 78
> 91
> 104
> 117
> 130
> 143
> 156
> 169
> 182
> 195
> ```

Obviamente, en situaciones "normales" lo más simple y eficiente es hacer:

```
def divide_entre_13(x: int) -> bool:
    return not x % 13
```